# invoke javascript function on tabindex change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want have link on click of that link a javascript function is called. Now i want to invoke that function using tab key. so when the focus goes to the link using tab key, the javascript function should be called.

How to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried binding the "focus" event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the onfocus event for the link. Something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:foo();" onfocus="foo();" >
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cw8Kd/) with little demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the event OnFocus on your link.

Answer (score 0):

Use event handler for focus and blur event of given link